# Trouble with hogman_minimal on OS X

Tags: macos-snowleopard, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Get the following errors. Has anyone done this install successfully? Seems to be related to csparse.

```
  Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libhogman_graph_optimizer_hogman.dylib
  Undefined symbols:
    "_cs_ereach", referenced from:
        AISNavigation::cs_chol_workspace(cs_sparse const*, cs_symbolic const*, int*, double*)in csparse_helper.o
    "_cs_spalloc", referenced from:
        AISNavigation::cs_chol_workspace(cs_sparse const*, cs_symbolic const*, int*, double*)in csparse_helper.o
    "_cs_ndone", referenced from:
        AISNavigation::cs_chol_workspace(cs_sparse const*, cs_symbolic const*, int*, double*)in csparse_helper.o
    "_cs_ipvec", referenced from:
        AISNavigation::cs_cholsolinvblocksymb(cs_sparse const*, double**, int, int, int, int, double*, cs_symbolic const*, double*, double*, double*, int*)in csparse_helper.o
        AISNavigation::cs_cholsolinvblocksymb(cs_sparse const*, double**, int, int, int, int, double*, cs_symbolic const*, double*, double*, double*, int*)in csparse_helper.o
        AISNavigation::cs_cholsolsymb(cs_sparse const*, double*, cs_symbolic const*, double*, int*)in csparse_helper.o
    "_cs_symperm", referenced from:
        AISNavigation::cs_chol_workspace(cs_sparse const*, cs_symbolic const*, int*, double*)in csparse_helper.o
    "_cs_nfree", referenced from:
        AISNavigation::cs_cholsolinvblocksymb(cs_sparse const*, double**, int, int, int, int, double*, cs_symbolic const*, double*, double*, double*, int*)in csparse_helper.o
        AISNavigation::cs_cholsolsymb(cs_sparse const*, double*, cs_symbolic const*, double*, int*)in csparse_helper.o
    "_cs_ltsolve", referenced from:
        AISNavigation::cs_cholsolinvblocksymb(cs_sparse const*, double**, int, int, int, int, double*, cs_symbolic const*, double*, double*, double*, int*)in csparse_helper.o
        AISNavigation::cs_cholsolinvblocksymb(cs_sparse const*, double**, int, int, int, int, double*, cs_symbolic const*, double*, double*, double*, int*)in csparse_helper.o
        AISNavigation::cs_cholsolsymb(cs_sparse const*, double*, cs_symbolic const*, double*, int*)in csparse_helper.o
    "_cs_calloc", referenced from:
        AISNavigation::cs_chol_workspace(cs_sparse const*, cs_symbolic const*, int*, double*)in csparse_helper.o
    "_cs_pvec", referenced from:
        AISNavigation::cs_cholsolinvblocksymb(cs_sparse const*, double**, int, int, int, int, double*, cs_symbolic const*, double*, double*, double*, int*)in csparse_helper.o
        AISNavigation::cs_cholsolinvblocksymb(cs_sparse const*, double**, int, int, int, int, double*, cs_symbolic const*, double*, double*, double*, int*)in csparse_helper.o
        AISNavigation::cs_cholsolsymb(cs_sparse const*, double*, cs_symbolic const*, double*, int*)in csparse_helper.o
    "_cs_lsolve", referenced from:
        AISNavigation::cs_cholsolinvblocksymb(cs_sparse const*, double**, int, int, int, int, double*, cs_symbolic const*, double*, double*, double*, int*)in csparse_helper.o
        AISNavigation::cs_cholsolinvblocksymb(cs_sparse const*, double**, int, int, int, int, double*, cs_symbolic const*, double*, double*, double*, int*)in csparse_helper.o
        AISNavigation::cs_cholsolsymb(cs_sparse const*, double*, cs_symbolic const*, double*, int*)in csparse_helper.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [../lib/libhogman_graph_optimizer_hogman.dylib] Error 1
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hogman_graph_optimizer_hogman.dir/all] Error 2
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9332/trouble-with-hogman_minimal-on-os-x/) by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2011-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Welcome to the amusing world of ROS on OS X!

Because there are no pre-built packages for csparse (either in MacPorts or ROS), you'll need to install it from source (see [the wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/csparse)). Then, if you add `<depend package="csparse"/>` to `manifest.xml` in hogman_minimal, and issue `rosmake`, it should compile.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1